# Ajax query using Jquery to ASP.NET webservice giving "Bad Request" only for methods with parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, json

I am having issues calling an ASP.NET web service in JQuery. I am basically following all the instructions on:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211489/Using-JSON-with-ASP-NET-3-5

I have written the Web service and the console server in C# and ASP.NET.

My JQuery is as follows:

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=ut-8",
    username: "John",
    password: "Doe",
    url: "https://machinename:8043/WtfService/HelloWorldPostSimple1",
    data: '{"firstName":"John"}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The first line allows for cross domain calls in IE which works. If I call a web service method that doesn't accept parameters, it works 100% for GET and POST.

My web service method is as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "HelloWorldPostSimple1")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "WtfUser")]
public string HelloWorldPostSimple1(string firstName)
{
    return string.Format("Hello {0} {1}", firstName, "Doe");
}
```

I've tried specifically putting in the Request and Response formats as JSON but still no luck.

Comment: have you tried adding: `contentType: "application/json",` in the ajax?

Comment: yes, it is there in the ajax call

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but I noticed the article you linked to is making the mistake of manually JSON-serializing the response. Make sure you don't do that. More info: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: I have a similar service running, but it has a `[OperationContract]` decorator on the method in my intance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would cause any of your issues, but the contentType charset should be utf-8 (you are missing the "f")

Comment: Ah bloody hell! Thanks a lot Dave! That was it :P

Comment: FYI, with the 1.7.1 version you do not even need that part of the contentType, hence my earlier comment suggestion.  Glad this fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone.

Turns out utf-8 was spelt wrong :(

Thanks Dave Simione for picking that up!

Answer (score 1):

Change this `data: '{"firstName":"John"}',` to `data: { firstName: "John" }`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a parameter in jQuery.ajax, "crossDomain" defaulted to false, have you tried setting that to true?

Comment: I have. Still doesn't work. My other calls to web service methods not requiring parameters do work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [JSON.org free JavaScript JSON parser](https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js).  This will convert an object into a well formatted JSON request (example below).

```
var jsonRequest = { firstName: "John" };

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest)
});
```

Comment: thanks, I hadn't tried that but unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: JSON.stringify() will fix malformed JSON (wrong/missing quotes).  If your still having errors, you should use Firebug to look at your JSON request to see if anything looks "weird".